# Alternative to MATCH function on horizontal data

Tags: excel, vba, function

This function is supposed to compute take the number "days", express it in terms of "years", and find an approximate match in the worksheet.

Then it takes the value of the cell below this approximate match and adds the "shift" to its value. This is what a part of my data look like.

[image: This is how my data in Excel look like]

Here is my code

```
Public Function Bucket(range As range, years As Long, shift As Long)
    days = years * 365
    approx_days = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(range, Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(days, range, 1))
    rate_approx_days = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(range, Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(days, range, 1) + 1)
    Bucket = rate_approx_days + shift
End Function


Sub try()
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Debug.Print (Bucket(.range("A14:AX14"), 1, 1))
    End With
End Sub
```

If it worked, the number 0.99636 (-0.00364+1) should appear in the immediate window, but I get 370.

Is there any alternative  that I could use on horizontal data so that it worked correctly or any way I could modify the function?

Comment: `Match` requires either a single column or row as its input. You're passing a range that has multiple rows and columns, hence the error.

Comment: @Rory thanks, I changed it to "A14:AX14". But I get the result 370...

Comment: Well, yes - you're only using the first row of data. You should pass the full range to the function but specify that the match applies to `range.rows(1)` only, not the whole range. PS `range` is not a good name for a variable.

Comment: Where  should I write  range.rows(1) to specify it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Don't use `Range` as a variable name it is a reserved word.
2. `Index()` returns a range
3. use `Offset` to move from your indexed `approx_days` one row down
4. Use `Option Explicit` and declare all your variables

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Function Bucket(ByVal Rng As Range, ByVal Years As Long, ByVal Shift As Long) As Double
    Dim Days As Long
    Days = Years * 365

    Dim approx_days As Range
    Set approx_days = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Rng, Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Days, Rng, 1))

    Dim rate_approx_days As Range
    Set rate_approx_days = approx_days.Offset(1, 0)

    Bucket = rate_approx_days + Shift
End Function


Sub try()
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Debug.Print Bucket(.Range("A14:AX14"), 1, 1)
    End With
End Sub
```

---

I recommend to implement some error handler and return an error value if something with `Match`/`Index` goes wrong.

```
Option Explicit

Public Function Bucket(ByVal Rng As Range, ByVal Years As Long, ByVal Shift As Long) As Variant
    On Error GoTo ERR_HANDLING 'if something goes wrong return error value
    Dim Days As Long
    Days = Years * 365

    Dim approx_days As Range
    Set approx_days = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Rng, Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Days, Rng, 1))

    Dim rate_approx_days As Range
    Set rate_approx_days = approx_days.Offset(1, 0)

    Bucket = rate_approx_days + Shift

    On Error GoTo 0

    Exit Function
ERR_HANDLING:
    Bucket = CVErr(xlErrNA) 'return N/A error
    Err.Clear
End Function


Sub try()
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Dim Result As Variant
        Result = Bucket(.Range("A14:AX14"), 1, 1)

        If IsError(Result) Then
            Debug.Print "Error occured"
        Else
            Debug.Print Result
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Note that the `Bucket` function now returns a `Variant/Double` or in case of error a `Variant/Error`. Therefore the function is declared as `Variant` now.